# setUp and tearDown for Scenrio outline (cucumber-jvm)

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I'm using scenario outline in my code and wanted to execute some code before the start of scenario outline and some code after the scenario outline execution has completed.

I know there are @Before and @After annotations in cucumber but these gets executed before and after every scenario. So if I have a scenario outline and 3 rows of example data then @Before and @After will be executed each of then i.e. total 3 times each.

But I want to execute it only once, @Before scenario outline and @After scenario outline thats it! Is there any way to achieve this in cucumber-jvm?

```
//@Before (some code that should be executed before scenario outline execution begins)

Scenario outline
....
Examples:
|Header1  | Header2 | ..etc
|Data1    | Data2   |

//@After (some code that should be executed after scenario outline execution ends)
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know there is no direct way, but you can tag your scenario and use the before and after hooks for tags as a workaround.

Here is an example:

```
Feature: ExampleTagging
    @DoBeforeScenarioX
    Scenario outline
    ....
    Examples:
    |Header1  | Header2 | ..etc
    |Data1    | Data2   |
```

Then you can use this in your Java code:

```
@Before("@DoBeforeScenarioX")
public void do_this_before_scenarioX() {....}

@After("@DoBeforeScenarioX")
public void do_this_after_scenarioX() {....}
```

Here are tags described: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags